# How to run infinite loop in Django and Display Message on template after each Loop without breaking the loop

Tags: python, django, loops

I need a run a function infinitely until we manually stop it. But after executing each loop we have to display the current loop result in the template. After displaying the result it continues to the next loop.

How to execute this process flow. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, the functions that are in the views.py file are called every time a request is made by the user.

Writting in views.py a infinite loop is just impossible but there is way to do what you want :

- You can add in the template a js function to reload the page and request the page to your server. I don't know what you want to do in your infinite loop but you can use variables and increase every time the page is called.
- If you want to refresh dynamically without refreshing the webpage every time : you can create a python file like "infiniteLoop.py" and edit a json/txt in media folder and a js function can check it every x sec.
  Or if you want to do that properly, you can use node and socket.io to send the data to the user.

The 2nd choice is maybe the best, I hope it helps !

Comment: If it helps you, you can put my answer as the solution and your issue will be closed